# What is the 'Primary Information' field group id in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In my User Event script I am adding a field to the form and I would like to add it to the Primary Information field group. What is the internal id of the group? I've tried primaryinformation but that's not correct. I can't see a method of iterating field groups and fields in the API to figure it out.

Does anyone know?

I am using SS2.

```
               var field = scriptContext.form.addField({
                        id: 'textfield',
                        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                        label: 'Text',
                        container: '**primaryinformation**' <--
                    });
```

Comment: Hi Man, Did you find a solution for your question ? I'm looking into same issue. Please if you found something, please let me know.

Comment: @NadeemKhoury Sorry - I never found a solution and NS support wasn't any help either. It doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting the DOM of the form, it looks like they are randomly generated identifiers in the form `fieldGroupXX`.

[image]

As an alternative, you could try using [`form.insertField(options)`](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4339707334.html) to place your field in the desired Field Group.